# Возникает ошибка Python script path must be set при запуске отладки на Django

Tags: python, django, отладка

Начал создавать сайт на Django. Дошёл до подключения режима отладки и возникли проблемы при запуске дебагера. Настройка режима отладки и возникающая ошибка на скрине снизу слева. Точки остановки проставил. Я полагаю, дело здесь не в коде.

[image: возникающая ошибка]
[image: настройка режима отладки]

Comment: manage.py нужно Script path перенести, а runserver оставить в Parameters

Comment: Insolor, благодарю за ответ, всё заработало! Если я правильно понимаю, Script Path - это путь к скрипту (файлу), который уже содержит определенные параметры, которые мы хотим запустить при отладке (runserver)?

Comment: Да, все так. Просто обычно в script path свой скрипт указывают, а тут нужно пусковой скрипт джанги указать.